# How to know user touch on pattern screen?

Tags: android, android-service

I wants to know that when user try to unlock the screen of pattern?how to get the on touch event of pattern of lock screen?

Comment: Please brief your question. What pattern are you talking about ? Do you want to get the Lock button event of the device ?

Comment: @GrIsHu yes.I want to get the lock button event of device.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides several APIs that let you help to know whether a user interface control is focusable and even request that a control be given focus:

Directional controls when its android:focusable attribute is set to true.

```
setFocusable()

isFocusable()

requestFocus()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to dectect screen locking, i think the following will work:

```
    @Override
 protected void onPause()
  { 
      super.onPause();

     // If the screen is off then the device has been locked
          PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (!isScreenOn) {

      // The screen has been locked 
        // do stuff...
     }
 }
```

**EDITED:**

you can also handle Screen lock using `Intent`

Check [Handling Screen OFF and Screen ON Intents](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I will try it and let you know.